# Gitlab Merge local branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, local

I have three branches `master`, `env1` and `env2`. `env1` has some changes and merged into `master` without conficts.

`env2` also has some changes but getting merge conflicts when created merge request. I have resolved the confilcted files and commited in `env2`  but before creating merge request I want to check the whole functinality if code breaks or not, is it possible to merge `env2` to master locally without creating a merge request in the main repo?

Comment: Of course it is possible

Comment: I wrote an answer. Please take a look at it and upvote and/or accept if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to merge local branch `env2` into the local `master` branch.

```sh
(env2) $ git checkout master
(master) $ git merge env2
```

Now, your local `master` branch is ahead of `origin/master`. You didn't yet pushed the changes to the `origin/master`. If your local changes are the good ones, then you can just do `git push origin master` to sync `origin/master` with you local `master`. If your local changes are the bad ones, then just remove them or reset your local master to the state on remote `git reset --hard origin/master`.

However, in a good workflow your local copy of `master` is just a copy of the one in remote, so you should never do these kind of things like merging to the local `master`.

Comment: Whyever not? Merges to remote master are automatically deployed, if you want to verify no-conflict what other choice but to test the merge locally? This seems like a completely normal use case.